# How to add different text color to progressbar active and inactive area?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I am adding the code with executable result below, What I need is white color to the text that appear throughout the progressbar active section.
ie till `€1,000,7` the color should be white and remaining whatever outside the active section should be blue `,710 paid`

Also note that the progressbar will move dynamically to the right, so the colouring should vary accordingly, I am ok if someone edit the existing html also would be fine for me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
  body{
    width:600px;
}
.progress-bar-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress-bar {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #377db7;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.containerd {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

span#load-amount {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    color: #377db7 !important;
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
}

span#load-target {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    color: #377db7 !important;
    margin-top: 0;
    right: 13px;
    font-family: Comfortaa;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.progress-bar span {
    background: #4c9fe3;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
</style>
<script src=""></script>
<body>
  <div class="progress-bar-wrap" id="progress-barwrap" style="">
      <div class="progress-bar">
          <span id="load-percent" style="width:10% !important;" class="load-progress"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="containerd">
          <span class="amount" id="load-amount">€1,000,710 paid</span>
          <span class="target" id="load-target">target €1,000,000</span>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a progressbar with inverted text color for "progressed" part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909494/how-to-create-a-progressbar-with-inverted-text-color-for-progressed-part)