# Text blended over background color

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a progress bar which looks like this:

[image: progress]

The left part can have different colors (green, orange, etc) and I want the text to change color according to the background underneath. Ideally, it should be black/dark-grey over the light-grey right part (like in the example), same black/dark-grey when the left part is rather light, and white when the left part is rather dark (like the green in the example).

I tried various `mix-blend-mode: difference` and `color` combinations, couldn't achieve this.
Bare example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3mh8vL8e/)
I tried also something along `filter: grayscale(1) contrast(9);`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
}

.progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #43a047;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress"></div>
  <div class="text">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. jsfiddle added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create another gradient to color the text without the use of mix-blend mode:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #43a047 50%, #eee 0);
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, black 0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

And for better flexibility you can use CSS variable to control the progress:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #43a047 var(--p,50%), #eee 0);
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white var(--p,50%), black 0);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--p:80%">
  <div class="text">Some text here</div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="--p:20%">
  <div class="text">Some text here</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Some text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's indeed simpler with the gradient, but 1) what about the webkit-specific properties? 2) now the text over the left part is always white, but I need it to be dark when the color is light (e.g. #ff9800)

Comment: @stanley90 1) I added the non webkit one and you can have more information here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip 2) as you can see you can specify the color you want, as you have now two gradient, so simple change white with any color you want