# How to add text in the center of a progress bar and color it depending on the progress value with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Having a basic HTML question. I wrote the following question:

```
<div class="low">
  <div class="chart">
    <div class="cover-fill" style="width: 91%"></div>
    <div class="cover-empty" style="width: 9%"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.low .chart { border: 1px solid #C21F39 }
.medium .chart { border: 1px solid #666; }
.high .chart { border: 1px solid rgb(77,146,33) }

.low .cover-fill { background: #C21F39 }
.medium .cover-fill { background: #666; }
.high .cover-fill { background: rgb(77,146,33) }

.cover-fill, .cover-empty {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 15px;
}

.chart {
  line-height: 0;
}

.cover-full {
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

I basically creates the following bar:

[image]

I would like to add numbers in the center of the bar itself. The wanted result is:

[image]

I tried to use the `<p>` tag in the chart `div` but it didn't work. What CSS should I use in order to make it work?

Comment: related to apply some effect to the text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50103065/8620333

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify your code like this:

```css
.chart {
  border: 1px solid #C21F39;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#C21F39, #C21F39);
  background-size: var(--progress) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  
  /* to center the text horizontally and vertically */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" style="--progress:75%">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:25%">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:43%">text</div>
```

Center the text in filled area:

```css
.chart {
  border: 1px solid #C21F39;
  height: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#C21F39, #C21F39);
  background-size: var(--progress) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding-right: calc(100% - var(--progress));
  color: #fff;
  
  /* to center the text horizontally and vertically */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" style="--progress:43%">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:80%">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:20%">text</div>
```

I used `hsl()` and some math to set background color depending on the progress.

```css
.chart {
  border: 1px solid #C21F39;
  height: 15px;
  --p: calc((var(--progress) / 100) * 120); /* some math to calculate hsl. reference https://coderwall.com/p/dvsxwg/smoothly-transition-from-green-to-red */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(calc(120 - var(--p)), 100%, 50%), hsl(calc(120 - var(--p)), 100%, 50%));
  background-size: calc(var(--progress) * 1%) 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding-right: calc(100% - (var(--progress) * 1%));
  color: #000;
  
  /* to center the text horizontally and vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart" style="--progress:100">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:80">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:20">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:50">text</div>
<div class="chart" style="--progress:5">text</div>
```