# Make specific letters in another color

Tags: html, css

I got a text and behind the text is an SVG Blob. I want the Letters in front of the blob to be another color. Is this possible?

[image: Blob with text Example]

Comment: Perhaps post your svg?

Comment: [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50102790/104380

Comment: @vsync, none of these answers are using svg though

Comment: @vanowm `svg` or not is irrelevant. Please try before dismissing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for ?

```css
.invert-bg{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
filter: invert(1);
}
.circle{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: white;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
}
p{
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 1.5rem;

color: white;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="invert-bg">
<div class="circle"></div>
<p>ontrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from section ethics, ver</p>
</div>
```